# C++ pig latin translator

Tags: c++, string

im writing a program in C++ that translates a sentence into pig latin, only by taking the first letter of the word and taking it to the end then and adding "ay" example "hello world" becomes "ellohay orldway" but its not working, ive tried several different ways none are working, at this point im about to give up, please can some one help me do this right.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void seperator(char []);

int main()
{
    string input;
    const int SIZE = 40;
    char sent[SIZE];

    cout << " enter sentence " << endl;
    cin >> input;
    cin.getline(sent, SIZE);
    seperator(sent);
    cout << input << endl;


    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

void seperator(char input[])
{
    int count = 0;
    char x;
    while (input[count] != '\0')
        count++;
    if (isalpha(input[count]))
        x =input[count];
    if (input[count] == ' ')
        input[count] = (x + ' ');
    if (input[count] == ' ')
        input[count] = 'ay';


}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: well it seems to be deleting everything but the first work... i dont understand why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `cin >> input;` is only getting the string up till the first whitespace, so the space between `hello` and `world`.

That's why it appears to be deleting everything but the first word, you should use something like
`std::getline (std::cin,input);`

Comment: Also use `string` for everything, instead of char arrays.